# How to call and re-run specific class from testng.xml

Tags: java, selenium, testing, automated-tests, testng

In my `testng.xml` file, I had some set of classes. I want to trigger a specific class from `testng.xml` in **testmethod**.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite">
    <test name="test">
        <classes>
            <class name="TempTest1"/>
            <class name="TempTest2"/>
            <class name="TempTest3"/>
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

TestNG test method

```java
@Test()
public void tearDown() {
    //tearDown
    TestNG testng = new TestNG();
    List<String> suites = Lists.newArrayList();
    suites.add("testng.xml");//path to xml..
    testng.setTestSuites(suites);
    testng.run();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to run a class **programmatically** :

```
TestNG testng = new TestNG();
testng.setTestClasses(new class [] {TempTest2.class});
testng.run();
```

In this case **TempTest2** should run

Comment: What if I had multiple suites and wanted to run one class from the specific suite.

Comment: may be a full qualified class path is required in that case in place of `TempTest2.class`

Comment: Okay, Could you please tell me how can I limit re run? as you can see in the teardown method I should validate the above test methods like (test1, test2...testn) if any of these got failed I should check them in the teardown test method and should re-run the complete suite. What if my environment is not working then tests will fail frequently so based on my script it will form a loop of continuous executions. I have to trigger a Jenkins job now it would become more hactic. Please suggest.

Comment: You surely do not wanna do a continuous executions in a loop. Cause in that case execution time would be undermined. tearDown is not meant for this purpose. What you can do instead in case of failures is that make use of `Listners`  - probably you should override `onTestFailure()` method from `ITestListners`

Comment: Is there any way to maintain counter globally? by declaring global `variable`

Comment: If it's a simple counter, and if you do not care about static and Instance variable.. declare in your test base class and make it static